# JavaScript/MooTools: IE 6?

Tags: javascript, mootools, browser-detection

What's the easiest way to tell if the browser is an IE 6 version in JavaScript? We're using MooTools here and `Browser.Engine.trident` will be `true` if it's IE, but what about the version number?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (Browser.Engine.trident4) alert('is IE6');
```

Comment: That is deprecated and doesn't exist in any version greater than the one you included a link to. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: The Browser class *is* in their current docs though. Another quick Google and we have an answer.

Comment: @JamesBrownIsDead: `Browser.Engine.<engineName><engineVersion>` isn't at ALL deprecated and is infact included in all Mootools versions starting 1.2. It is just generated dynamically instead of generated statically. But if you still believe it is deprecated, use `Browser.Engine.name` and `Browser.Engine.version`. +1 to Oli.

Comment: quite, the `Browser` collection in mootools is _entirely_ based upon feature detection and not only is it not being deprecated but it's being added to (things like css3 feature detect, base64 detect, etc) are all plugins you can extend `Browser` with. I think he meant that window.ie6 (from mootools 1.1.1) got deprecated though.

Comment: His first comment was based on my original answer which did use the deprecated `window.ie6` attribute.

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff and @Andrew Moore  Please clarify because according to [this](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Browser/Browser#Browser:Browser-Platform): _"The Browser.Engine object is deprecated since MooTools 1.3."_

Answer (score -1):

Just to keep this up to date.  Most current version of Mootools you need:

```
if (Browser.ie6) alert('is IE6');
```